How to allow just one user to use SSH?
I just want to make, for example, admin user to login using SSH and not other users to use SSH. I don't want to deny just one user, I want to deny all users excepts admin user.

I once wrote an elaborate answer on my preferred SSH configuration. That configuration may be a good fit for you too.

By default if no AllowUsers directive is found in /etc/ssh/sshd_config everyone is allowed access, however a single AllowUsers directive would allow (and restrict) access only to users listed in the directive, so all you need is:
AllowUsers username

in /etc/ssh/sshd_config, where username is the user you want to allow access to the machine.
Remember to restart ssh.service for the modification to take place:
sudo systemctl restart ssh.service


To keep the modification out of the main /etc/ssh/sshd_config file and for tidyness, you could create an additional configuration file in /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d instead:
f=/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/50-allowusers.conf

! [ -f "${f}" ] &&
    <<<'AllowUsers username' sudo tee "${f}"

Again, remember to restart ssh.service for the modification to take place:
sudo systemctl restart ssh.service


To explicitly single out one or more users instead:
DenyUsers username1 username2 username3

Again, remember to restart ssh.service for the modification to take place:
sudo systemctl restart ssh.service


On some (most?) distributions, you can use SSH config override files in something like /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/. This avoids having to modify the main sshd config file, which is easier to manage and more robust against package upgrades.

@marcelm I agree, I added a way to do the same using config files
